# React Native - Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.isLoggedIn.then)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm the beginner of react native, I'm developing small app to show feeds from firebase database, if the user is logged in. So after calling isloggedin function, I'm using then function to show firebase data.

This is the my isLoggedIn function:

```
export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if(user){
          Actions.main();
          dispatch({
              type:LOGGED_IN
          })
      }else {
          Actions.auth();
          dispatch({
              type:NOT_LOGGED_IN
          })
      }
    });
  }
};
```

and I'm calling the isLoggedIn function in componentDidMount function;

```
componentDidMount (){
    this.props.isLoggedIn()
        .then(() => {
            this.props.fetchTweet();
        });
}
```

But I'm getting error like this: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.isLoggedIn().then')
I expected from my code show my firebase data.
By the way fetchTweet is working without then function and isLoogedin also works if I don't use 'then'

Comment: then expects a promise, are you returning one?

Comment: I never used promise, I always call then like this but this time it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work as `this.props.isLoggedIn()` returns a function which accepts a dispatch object. This action will be intercepted by redux thunk (a middleware). Thus this is not returning a promise so it is not **thennable**. It will produce the error. The proper method is:

```
componentDidMount (){
    // calling only the action creator
    this.props.isLoggedIn()
}
```

Listening for the Action in reducer like:

```
// Typical reducer
function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
   case LOGGED_IN : 
    // change your state according to the business logic
    // for example make a flag IsLoggedIn and make it true
     const changed_state =  // Your changed state
     return changed_state
   default:
     return state;
 }
```

Inject state from mapStateToProps to Component and then perform the logic and then perform the `this.props.fetchTweet()`.

```
// Implementing mapStateToProps function
 const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
   // get the key from the state
   const loginSuccess = state.IsLoggedIn
   return {
        loginSuccess
        }
```

```
componentWilReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if(nextProps.loginSuccess && this.props.loginSuccess !== nextProps.loginSuccess) {
 this.props.fetchTweet()
}
}
```

Comment: really!!?? Thanks :)